# How to add customer headers with AngularJS and Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add a header into Restangular `X-CSRFToken`. How can I do this?

**This is what I have tried:**

```
.controller("LoginFormController", ['$scope', 'Restangular', "NoBaseURL",
        function ($scope, Restangular, NoBaseURL) {
            // Submit form
            $scope.submit = function () {

                var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();


                post_data = {
                    username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password,
                    Restangular.headers: {'X-CSRFToken':token},
                }

                var login_post = NoBaseURL.all('/login/').post(post_data)

                event.preventDefault();
            }

        }])
```

Comment: do you want to add it to every request as a default parameter or a specific one?

Comment: @wickY26 only to this request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default post method of **restangular**

```
post(subElement, elementToPost, [queryParams, headers])
```

**(from document)** Does a POST and creates a subElement. Subelement is mandatory and is the nested resource. Element to post is the object to post to the server

**EXAMPLE**

```
account.customPOST({name: "My Message"}, "", {}, {headerKey : "headerValue"})
```

so if we turn it to your solution it would be something like this

```
NoBaseURL.all('/login/').post(post_data, "", {}, {'X-CSRFToken':token})
```

hope it helps...

Comment: I can get it to work this way around: post_data, "", {"X-CSRFToken": token}, {}